# Is it possible to create an event in an abstract class?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, abstract-class

I have abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public delegate void ContextMenuClickHandler(object sender, Point point);
    public event ContextMenuClickHandler OnContextMenuClick;

    public void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        OnContextMenuClick(this, new Point((int) x, (int) y));
    }
}
```

and I plug event:

```
Base.ContextMenuClickHandler += ShowContextMenu;//error

void ShowContextMenu(object sender, Point point)
{

}
```

error:

> 'Base.ContextMenuClickHandler' is a 'type', which is not valid in the
>   given context

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OnContextMenuClick += ShowContextMenu;//fix
```

you used the wrong variable. `OnContextMenuClick` is your event that you subscribe to.

but in your case, why do not use a virtual method?

Comment: Good, and need to add static public static event ContextMenuClickHandler OnContextMenuClick;

Comment: you should not make a public static property in an nonstatic class. first of all, its not unittestable, second you mix inside one context 2 different lifetimes, that can lead to hard to find bugs... if you need to have it everywhere available, try out the command pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you are using the event type, ContextMenuClickHandler, instead of the event name, OnContextMenuClick.  Try the following

```
base.OnContextMenuClick += ShowContextMenu
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example here, have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy3sefw3.aspx